# Compute the limit of a bounded integral by checking for uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, integration, uniform-convergence, riemann-integration

Compute

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int^{1}_{0}\left (x+\frac{x^2}{n+e^x}\right )\,dx$

With reasoning

--

I have come to the conclusion that what I am required to do is to show that the integrand converges uniformly on $(0,1)$, meaning that it will in turn be Riemann integrable and we can use the following fact which holds if this criteria is met:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int^{1}_{0}x+\frac{x^2}{n+e^x}dx=\int^{1}_{0}\lim_{n\to\infty} (x+\frac{x^2}{n+e^x})dx$

How then would I go about proving that the function $(x+\frac{x^2}{n+e^x})$ is uniformly convergent on $(0,1)$?

Comment: Could it be something to do with the pointwise limit?

Comment: Do you mean $n\to \infty?$

Comment: Yes I do, thanks for pointing this out. I'll change it now!

Comment: It would be good to put some parentheses on the integran, as I just did in your second line.

Comment: Apparently, the limit of the integrand should be $x$. So how could you bound $\left | x + \frac{x^2}{n+e^x} - x \right |= \frac{x^2}{n+e^x} $ by some quantity that is independent of $x$, and tends to $0$?